# Why am I able to execute JARs directly from bash?

Tags: java, linux, bash

I'm a longtime Java guy, and know that the way to run a JAR with a main class referenced in a `MANIFEST.MF` file within the Jar is easy:

`java -jar theJar.jar`

I was using this to start up the Fabric3 server (contained in `bin/server.jar` in its standard distribution). I noticed that when I unpacked it from the distribution tarball, it was flagged as executable. On a whim, I tried

`./server.jar`

from my `bash` command line (`bash` version 4.1.5 in Ubuntu 10.10), and lo and behold, the server started up as if I had typed the normal `java -jar ...` command. The JAR is structured like a normal JAR; I did a `head` on it, and there was no `#!` command in the first few bytes, so `bash` shouldn't magically know to start a Java VM with it, right? Or has this version of `bash` grown the ability to start JARs with a proper manifest correctly? Inquiring minds want to know...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This may not be a feature of bash at all.  If you are running linux (as you have tagged) you may have the `binfmt_misc` kernel module, which does a little bit of magic, when you try to execute a program.  Basically what this does is it extends the binary formats that linux can execute from just elf to also include some user defined formats, with enough instructions to run them.

Comment: Yup that's it.  You can run update-binfmts --display on Ubuntu 10.10 to see the list if handlers that are installed.

Comment: gnarly, apparently I can execure llvm bytecode from the command line ^^.

Answer (score 2):

It's not bash which has grown this strange ability - it's your kernel, specifically the module [binfmt_misc](http://git.kernel.org/gitweb.cgi?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/binfmt_misc.txt;hb=HEAD). (There's also some [documentation specific to Java](http://git.kernel.org/gitweb.cgi?p=linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux-2.6.git;a=blob;f=Documentation/java.txt;hb=HEAD))